# How can I change format of a string when I use gets

Tags: ruby

Lets say I need some info from user so I use
`license_plate = gets.chomp`
so the user enters

`01ABC222`or

`01 ABC 222` or

`01abc222` or

`01 abc 222`.

I want to write these license plates to a .yml file. I know the writing part but I want all the plates in the `01 ABC 222` format. How can I convert the given string into what I want?

Comment: `scan(/\d+|\D+/).map(&:upcase).map(&:strip).join(' ')` (give or take; untested)

Comment: You can even avoid `strip` if you do `/\d+|[^\s\d]+/`...

Answer (score 0):

```
license_plate.upcase.gsub(/[0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]/){|split_these| split_these.insert(1, " ")}
```

`/[0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]/` is a regular expression. It searches for a pattern in a string. In this case, it searches for a digit (`[0-9]`) followed directly by a letter (`[A-Z]`), or (`|`) a letter directly followed by a digit. If it find such a pattern then the block inserts a space in the middle (at index 1).